# Want to merge PDF in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, digital-signature, dompdf

I have documents in pdf form. And I have to merge all documents into a single pdf.
For this I am using PHP Merger with DOMpdf, It's working fine.

But if there are any pdf which is digitally signed or encrypted, then an error arise "FPDF error : File is encrypted!".
My Code is

```
$merger = new \PDFMerger;
foreach($jobDocumentsPdf as $documentPdf) {
$merger->addPDF(public_path().urldecode($documentPdf));
}
return $merger->merge('stream', "finalreport-$item->number.pdf");
```

How to resolve this error, I want to merge digitally signed pdf.

Comment: And what would you like to achieve? What is your question?

Comment: I want to merge digitally signed pdf.

Comment: Unfortunately, this cannot be done with PDF Merger. No signed pdf's can be merged because the signature is applied to a complete document and not to a region. You are not supposed to be able to modify a document without the key used to sign it, because if you could, there would be no point to signing anything.

Comment: Instead of merging the documents could you add the encrypted documents as attachments instead? This would achieve the goal of having the files all in one document, it may not be appropriate though based on how these "merged" documents are going to be used later on though.

Comment: http://www.ilovepdf.com/merge_pdf , see this link

Answer (score 0):

Signed documents are not be the problem here, because the signature and its annotation/appearance would simply not be copied to the resulting document (the class uses [FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/) internally).

The problem is an encrypted/protected PDF file. [FPDI does not support reading of such files](https://www.setasign.com/support/faq/fpdi/can-fpdi-import-encrypted-pdf-documents/#question-87).

Comment: Thanx ,

 But is there any way to merge encrypted pdf, if we don't have encryption/decryption key....

Comment: Ask for an unprotected version. Normally a document shouldn't be protected just for fun.

Comment: I guess we shouldn't discuss if and how a protection with an empty string as a password (which is the case if you do not need to enter a password) can be bypassed here.

Comment: I just want to merge pdf's, I don't care if after merged pdf has an invalid signature........        My aim is to just merge all pdf's and show it as a single   pdf file.

Comment: I fully understand your requirements. But your main question is related to FPDI. And my answer is still current in view to FPDI. SO isn't the right place to ask for tools. Feel free to contact us (Setasign) directly, so we can check if we may have a solution for you.